# Can the aria-live attribute of a given element itself be set dynamically with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, wai-aria

More specifically, if it is set with javascript will the screen reader/AT software still pick up the attribute and correctly announce any changes within the element to the user even though it was not present on page load?

If anyone has any experience of this I would appreciate any details you have.

Here's an example of what I want to achieve...

Before the javascript call:

```
<body>
```

Set a property with jQuery (or whatever)...

```
$('body').attr('aria-live', 'polite');
```

After call:

```
<body aria-live="polite">
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who has anything to add.

Comment: This might be of help http://stackoverflow.com/q/1871920/575527

Comment: Sorry Joseph I'm not sure to what you're referring on that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, depending on the context, the reader will pick up changes to attributes and announce updates to the users. This allows readers to be useful as chat or email clients, and is the purpose of the aria-live attribute. One use case is the "aria-selected" attribute, which can be assigned to navigation elements and can be used to indicate the "active" navigation item.

[Mozilla Developer Network ARIA live regions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions)

Comment: Thank you. That would seem to be a resounding, yes. Providing the attribute is added before the element is focused. So adding the attribute to the body element on page load should cover any subsequent page updates. Can you tell me if you have any direct experience using this method, and personally know that it works?

Comment: I have used basic ARIA attributes, but nothing scripted or particularly complex. That said, the first example I listed uses dynamically added attributes (not just changed attributes) and indicates that it works properly with the JAWS and NVDA readers and IE. Reader implementation seems to be even more fragmented than browser implementation, so serious testing should be the order of the day.

Comment: The MDN page says "Dynamically adding an element with an aria-live attribute or specialized role to the document also won't result in any announcement by assistive technologies (as, at that point, the browser/assistive technologies are not aware of the live region yet, so cannot monitor it for changes)."

And the ssbartgroup link is a 404